# Issue with reading from json file

Tags: python, json, class, for-loop, object

I'm working with project and I'm trying to write from json file. Unfortunately I found a problem. When I tried to read it I dont' get everything the same as this in my file pliki.json

```
pliki.json:
[

      {
            "name": "",
            "pesel": "",
            "choosendir": "Amsterdam-Berlin",
            "lot id": "1",
            "bilet class": "Biznes ",
            "bilet_price": " 68",
            "seat": "5"
      }
]
Function reading:
import csv
from lot import DatabaseofLoty, Lot
import json
from person import Person, Database
from ticket import Ticket
def read_info_aboutpeople(path):
    with open(path, "r") as file_handle:
        people = []
        try:
            rowing = json.load(file_handle)
            for row in rowing:
                name =row["name"],
                print(name)
                pesel = row["pesel"],
                print(pesel)
                choosendir = row["choosendir"]
                print(choosendir)
                lot_id = row["lot id"],
                print(lot_id)
                bilet_class = row["bilet class"],
                bilet_price = row["bilet_price"],
                seat = row["seat"]
                ticket = Ticket(bilet_class,bilet_price)
                person = Person(name, pesel,ticket, choosendir, lot_id, seat)
                people.append(person)
                database = Database(people)
                return database
        except Exception:
            database = Database([])
print(read_info_aboutpeople("pliki.json"))
```

Outputs:

```
('',)
('',)
Amsterdam-Berlin
('1',)
```

Why this works like that? How to solve this

Comment: What's the point of commas at the end of the line when assigning `name`, `pesel` etc.?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, you would like to get this?


Amsterdam-Berlin
1
?

Comment: your code is fine, just remove the comma at end of the assignment lines. In python 3.1, each row is a `dict` and able to get the field values. which version of python you are running?

Comment: change this line `name =row["name"],` to `name =row["name"]`, and so on.

Comment: don't use commas at end of line unless it's actually needed. the fix is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Actually json reading works, but look what exactly is happening here:

```
name = row["name"],
print(type(name)) # <class 'tuple'>
```

So in real you create one element tuple here with name as it's only element. That's why you see strange print results as most of your variables are just tuples (and that's why your code probably blows up when you use lot_id as you expect that as single str). You need to remove commas to make code work as you expect